# Stretch Swiffy SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, google-swiffy

How can I stretch the Swiffy result (SVG) to fit the entire page? (I can't add attributes to the SVG element because it is not there, swiffy generates it)

My swiffy:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Swiffy output</title>
    <script src="runtime.js"></script>

    <script>
        swiffyobject = { "internedStrings": ["::::080f080f"], "tags": [{ "frames": [], "scenes": [{ "name": "Scene 1", "offset": 0 }], "type": 23 }, { "bounds": [{ "ymin": 0, "ymax": 25600, "xmin": 0, "xmax": 15360 }], "id": 1, "fillstyles": [{ "color": [-6174960], "type": 1 }], "paths": [{ "fill": 0, "data": [":::a:600ya360o:a:600Yc"] }], "flat": true, "type": 1 }, { "id": 1, "matrix": 0, "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "id": 2, "height": 608, "width": 608, "data": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAmAAAAJgCAYAAAAta9/QAAAl8ElEQVR42u3d3W0jR5cG4MnAITgE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\n+H88a48XWWKZOwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg\u003d\u003d", "type": 8 }, { "bounds": [{ "ymin": -6080, "ymax": 6080, "xmin": -6080, "xmax": 6080 }], "id": 3, "fillstyles": [{ "transform": "45184l::45184l080F080F", "bitmap": 2, "type": 6 }], "paths": [{ "fill": 0, "data": [":080F080Fa:160la160l:a:160Lc"] }], "flat": true, "type": 1 }, { "tags": [{ "id": 3, "matrix": "#0", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "781D335x335X781D931e727e", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "397R5334d5334D397R926e341e", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "8865C9730e9730E8865C064f981d", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "3204F5430f5430F3204F327f699d", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "7706H1598f1598F7706H674f539d", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "4307J2640e2640E4307J964f511d", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "7870K9206c9206C7870K251g566d", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "7005L445v445V7005L513g704d", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "0936M774c774C0936M723g909d", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "9333L997N997n9333L864g161e", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "1149L4489C4489c1149L927g481e", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "7268J0394E0394e7268J888g804e", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "9071H1087F1087f9071H745g097f", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "8438F5462F5462f8438F520g330f", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "7711D3007F3007f7711D233g477f", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "8615B4023E4023e8615B911f526f", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "337M9455C9455c337M591f471f", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "457C803T803t457C302f318f", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }, { "replace": true, "matrix": "#0", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }], "id": 4, "frameCount": 20, "type": 7 }, { "id": 4, "matrix": "::::00q302k", "type": 3, "depth": 2 }, { "bounds": [{ "ymin": 2918, "ymax": 25600, "xmin": 0, "xmax": 15360 }], "id": 5, "fillstyles": [{ "color": [-10507490], "type": 1 }, { "color": [-4072357], "type": 1 }, { "color": [-1], "type": 1 }], "paths": [{ "fill": 0, "data": [":360o340la360O043ja:217ca360o:a:260Mc"] }, { "fill": 1, "data": [":485j146da:18db37D7N76I7Sa88I1Ca81Gia81Gia36Jaa37JAa9Pfb2Rp9S1tbE5fE5saa86kba05gF86kbB1n2d5wb6d8i8o4qb5o6j4w8jba:b:b4h:5v7Ja98q58Ma3e5Db8bV9eVbe:jaa99d97pbn9d1d9gby0c0g2eb8dw9n0fb7h7c6m4ha2e:a99B70Jb4Q27F89B74Jb4C1M2J5Tb8F3G9R9Jb6EQ2JQbP:1Cbb3Fi1L5ea19O88ka66D56caF0Gal15Vac8Cbc7M6m9Mb5kC0rCb3c:4eaa62gxa61gra56osa57ooa46e:a:15ta94V80Ia8c7ra9b8pbi7f5d9jb3c8c9i6fb90j70d55p28gb9x3k09e3kbo:0c:b7hB6nYb7fY5k3Ha:25Xb8G3H1R3Zb6K2T5R88Bc"] }, { "fill": 2, "data": [":204h929ba:00ha6o:a:00Hc:55fKa5Kia9ChaQ8la8fMa9fFb8h:4m5eb5d4e5d1qa:9gb:5eL4jbM1e7C5hbY5c7F7eb0Dt1Jtb1F:1JTb0DU8F8EbZ9C8C7HbL1EL9Ja:12Da9O:a:21db:1s5i90bb5i1j79b1jb6r:82b3Jb7i1J7i04Ca:6Ib:4HW5NbW2F2F0Jb0D7C6I7Eb5ER2LRc:87Pka2y96fa1Lya7Lpa0d1na7p9Bb8fK0o6Cb1gW7l5Eb7e2C8i0Hb1d7D4f6Kbv6Fv0Pa:02Da9O:a:99caE6hbE8cR8fbO3c5C2ebVw7E9ca9V44Fc:68D:a:33ka9o:a:33Kc"] }], "flat": true, "type": 1 }, { "id": 5, "matrix": 0, "type": 3, "depth": 9 }, { "bounds": [{ "ymin": -4719, "ymax": 5010, "xmin": -4719, "xmax": 4720 }], "id": 6, "paths": [{ "data": [":a549Db26I:71Q58cb17H45c46N75ib30F29f75I45nb58C46h58C71qb:26i58c71qb45c16h75i46nb29f29f46n75ib45h57c71q57cb26i:71q57Cb16h46C46n75Ib29f30F74i46Nb58c45H58c71Qb:25I58C71Qb45C16H74I45Nb30F30F46N75Ib46H58C71Q58Cc:81l16ob91e0y47j05gb55d56d05g47jb9y11f9y81lb:70f9Y82lb0Y90e05G46jb56D56d47J06gb11F9y81L9yb70F:82L9Yb91E0Y47J06Gb55D56D05G46Jb9Y12F9Y82Lb:70F9y81Lb0y91E05g47Jb56d55D47j05Gb12f9Y82l9Yb70f:81l9yc"], "line": 0 }], "flat": true, "linestyles": [{ "joint": 2, "color": [-6174960], "cap": 1, "width": [340], "miter": 10 }], "type": 1 }, { "tags": [{ "id": 6, "matrix": "::::549d549d", "type": 3, "depth": 1 }, { "type": 2 }], "id": 7, "frameCount": 1, "type": 7 }, { "id": 7, "matrix": "::::230d429l", "type": 3, "depth": 10 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "bounds": [{ "ymin": 3567, "ymax": 3743, "xmin": 6669, "xmax": 6858 }], "id": 8, "fillstyles": [{ "color": [-1], "type": 1 }], "paths": [{ "fill": 0, "data": [":763f567cb8C:6Fzb8B8b8B3fb:5c8b1fb8bz6fzb9c:7fZb8bY8b1Fb:6C8B3Fb8BZ7FZc"] }], "flat": true, "type": 1 }, { "id": 8, "matrix": 0, "type": 3, "depth": 12 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 4, "depth": 12 }, { "bounds": [{ "ymin": 3567, "ymax": 3743, "xmin": 6348, "xmax": 6858 }], "id": 9, "fillstyles": [{ "color": [-1], "type": 1 }], "paths": [{ "fill": 0, "data": [":442f567cb8C:7Fzb7B7b7B3fb:6c7b1fb9bz7fzb0d:7fZb8bY8b1Fb:6C8B3Fb7BZ7FZc:21c:b8C:6Fzb8B8b8B3fb:5c8b1fb8bz6fzb9c:7fZb8bY8b1Fb:6C8B3Fb8BZ7FZc"] }], "flat": true, "type": 1 }, { "id": 9, "matrix": 0, "type": 3, "depth": 13 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 4, "depth": 13 }, { "bounds": [{ "ymin": 3567, "ymax": 3743, "xmin": 6027, "xmax": 6858 }], "id": 10, "fillstyles": [{ "color": [-1], "type": 1 }], "paths": [{ "fill": 0, "data": [":120f567cb8C:6Fzb7B7b7B3fb:6c7b1fb8bz6fzb9c:8fZb7bY7b1Fb:6C7B3Fb9BZ8FZc:22c:b8C:7Fzb7B7b7B3fb:6c7b1fb9bz7fzb0d:7fZb8bY8b1Fb:6C8B3Fb7BZ7FZc:21c:b8C:6Fzb8B8b8B3fb:5c8b1fb8bz6fzb9c:7fZb8bY8b1Fb:6C8B3Fb8BZ7FZc"] }], "flat": true, "type": 1 }, { "id": 10, "matrix": 0, "type": 3, "depth": 14 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 4, "depth": 14 }, { "id": 9, "matrix": 0, "type": 3, "depth": 13 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 2 }, { "type": 4, "depth": 13 }, { "id": 8, "matrix": 0, "type": 3, "depth": 12 }, { "type": 2 }], "fileSize": 11203, "v": "5.2.0", "backgroundColor": -1, "frameSize": { "ymin": 0, "ymax": 25600, "xmin": 0, "xmax": 15360 }, "frameCount": 25, "frameRate": 24, "version": 15 };
    </script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; overflow: hidden">
    <div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    </div>
    <script>

        var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
                                     swiffyobject);

        stage.start();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying width and height in pixels.  This works for me.  Also, you may need to remove the overflow style.  If this works with your file then get the width and height of the page using JavaScript and apply to the swiffy container div